# I was wondering how to search if certain words are adjectives and/or adverbs

Tags: grammar

I have a project... due very soon and I'm having trouble finding words  that are both adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: Dictionaries give part-of-speech information. You might try looking up an adjective and seeing if it also has an entry as an adverb, and vice-versa. There may be a reference work out there that is organized by part-of-speech (or at least searchable that way) instead of alphabetically, but I'm personally not familiar with any.

Comment: For example, [*fast*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fast) (which also happens to be a verb and a noun, but with a **completely** different meaning). The only other one I can think of offhand is [*offhand*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/offhand). I'm sure there are more, but it looks like it's going to be a question of initial knowledge and then confirmation as @Dan suggests.

Comment: There are many fewer adverbs than adjectives. Start with a list of adverbs (ignore adverbs ending in -ly, they're not likely to be adjectives) and check if they are adjectives (either because you realize it, or a dictionary tells you). e.g. 'very' - obviously not an adjective, 'quick' hm... 'He ran quick' is that correct English? Not sure? Check a dictionary.

Comment: You might find this site interesting: http://www.visca.com/regexdict/

Answer (score 1):

Swan, in *Practical English Usage* (p24) has a long list of words that have the same form when modifying nouns and verbs. These include *clean, dead, fair, fast, fine, free, hard, just, sharp, short*, and *wide*.

As Swan notes, some of the adverbs in this list have a second form with a different meaning. For example, *hard* and *hardly*, *fair* and *fairly*, *fine* and *finely*. And some words that seem as if they should be adverbs are in fact adjectives; for example, *deadly* and *lively*.

A good dictionary will tell you the different senses of these words.